Is there any way In Apache beam Java to upsert (Update + Insert) the rows in BigQuery tables
Is there any way in apache beam java to update the rows in BigQuery table ? My use case is I run my dataflow job once in a day and it takes data from one BQ table and after transforming, it writes  to another BQ table. As part of the transformations, I will have to check whether it is the existing or a new record by comparing it with the output table. If it is existing record then I have to update else insert. This dataflow job has to read 5 million rows from table on daily basis and it has to do either insert or update to another BQ table.
Below are the ways that I know and I am not sure whether these are the best approaches.

By running UPDATE queries using beam on BigQuery. Here the problem is, if there are 10,000 rows that needs to be updated then it runs update query 10,000 times which is time consuming.
Writing the data to a BigQuery temp table and then running the MERGE query between temp and actual table so that data gets updated or inserted in the actual table.
I experimented with the streaming approach in Beam discussed in this issue: https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/27616. Although the Beam job successfully updates records in BigQuery, it keeps running indefinitely because it operates in streaming mode. The issue is that the job never completes.



PCollection<TableRow> rows1 = p.apply(BigQueryIO.readTableRows().from(" project.dataset.table1"));


PCollection<RowMutation> rowmutate = rows1.apply(MapElements
                .into(new TypeDescriptor<RowMutation>() {
                })
                .via(tableRow -> RowMutation.of(tableRow,
                        RowMutationInformation.of(RowMutationInformation.MutationType.UPSERT, new Random().nextLong(1,1000000)))));


        rowmutate.setCoder(RowMutation.RowMutationCoder.of())

                .apply(BigQueryIO.applyRowMutations()
                        .to(" project.dataset.table2")
                        .withSchema(createSchema())
                        .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STORAGE_API_AT_LEAST_ONCE)
                .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER))



please suggest me the best approach to make these UPSERTS on BigQuery using Apache beam.

My vote would be the MERGE recipe you mentioned.  The Beam job becomes no more than a transformer/loader into the temp table and then you can run the merge once a day.  You are now being pretty efficient in that there is only one operation to perform the upserts.
